# Is it inbuilt Magento 2 feature set zero shipping charge on certain total?

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.4

I am using the Magento community 2.4 version.

I would like to override and set a $0 charge to the `FedEx Ground` shipping method on above $400 subtotal, is there any inbuilt Magento 2 feature to achieve this functionality or make it a custom feature?

I tried and find out but I could not find out this kind of feature on the admin side?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it as a shopping cart sales rule,
You can set the action to be the shipping method you want with a certain subtotal, after that you should select "Free shipping"
see below:

[image]